# Using a custom argument validation helper breaks code analysis

Tags: c#, validation, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I'd like to use a custom helper to simplify argument validation, something like this.

```
public static void ThrowIfNull(this object value, string parameterName)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
    }
}
```

However, the static code analysis of course doesn't know that I do validate the input in public methods when using this helper, so it gives me `CA1062` errors about public method arguments not being validated.

The particular issue is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182182.aspx).

Is there a way to *teach* the code analyzer that this helper handles argument null validation? What is the proper solution for this issue?

Comment: @DipenShah Very easily. Try it: `try
            {
                string s = null;

                s.ThrowIfNull("s");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {/* set breakpoint here */
            }`

Comment: What kind of code analysys? There are many.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett interesting, good too know!

Comment: This kind of "standard" CA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182182.aspx

Comment: Show the method that causes the CA1062 or a simplified version

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create attribute with the following name:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class ValidatedNotNullAttribute : Attribute {}
```

Then apply it to the argument you are validating:

```
public static void ThrowIfNull([ValidatedNotNull] this object value, string parameterName)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
    }
}
```

And the warning should go away.

You can see this attribute is used by many libraries, including .net framework itself, for example [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/Validation/ValidatedNotNullAttribute.cs).

Comment: Thank you, I hoped that there's a technique like this, as for example ReSharper uses a similar kind of annotation to make such a helper work. I'll try this tomorrow and accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, it works but pity it's not documented anywhere, or at least I didn't found (unlike Resharper attributes).

Comment: I can't get this to work if I'm sharing this among many projects. I can only get this to work in a project if the project itself contains and defines this extension method. Any ideas?

Comment: In particular, Sonarqube supports [ValidatedNotNull] (proof: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/issues/5973 )